# Compile Boost Program

Tags: c++, boost, compilation, linker

I'm having trouble understanding the basics of compiling a boost program. I'm working with Fedora 15, with boost installed through yum in /usr/include/boost. I have boost build installed as well.

I'd really like to know how to link with the boost library and compile the following example under the terminal, and with boost-jam/build.

```
//
// reference_counted.cpp
// ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//
// Copyright (c) 2003-2011 Christopher M. Kohlhoff (chris at kohlhoff dot com)
//
// Distributed under the Boost Software License, Version 1.0. (See accompanying
// file LICENSE_1_0.txt or copy at http://www.boost.org/LICENSE_1_0.txt)
//

#include <boost/asio.hpp>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>
#include <boost/enable_shared_from_this.hpp>
#include <boost/shared_ptr.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

// A reference-counted non-modifiable buffer class.
class shared_const_buffer
{
public:
  // Construct from a std::string.
  explicit shared_const_buffer(const std::string& data)
    : data_(new std::vector<char>(data.begin(), data.end())),
      buffer_(boost::asio::buffer(*data_))
  {
  }

  // Implement the ConstBufferSequence requirements.
  typedef boost::asio::const_buffer value_type;
  typedef const boost::asio::const_buffer* const_iterator;
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* begin() const { return &buffer_; }
  const boost::asio::const_buffer* end() const { return &buffer_ + 1; }

private:
  boost::shared_ptr<std::vector<char> > data_;
  boost::asio::const_buffer buffer_;
};

class session
  : public boost::enable_shared_from_this<session>
{
public:
  session(boost::asio::io_service& io_service)
    : socket_(io_service)
  {
  }

  tcp::socket& socket()
  {
    return socket_;
  }

  void start()
  {
    using namespace std; // For time_t, time and ctime.
    time_t now = time(0);
    shared_const_buffer buffer(ctime(&now));
    boost::asio::async_write(socket_, buffer,
        boost::bind(&session::handle_write, shared_from_this()));
  }

  void handle_write()
  {
  }

private:
  // The socket used to communicate with the client.
  tcp::socket socket_;
};

typedef boost::shared_ptr<session> session_ptr;

class server
{
public:
  server(boost::asio::io_service& io_service, short port)
    : io_service_(io_service),
      acceptor_(io_service, tcp::endpoint(tcp::v4(), port))
  {
    session_ptr new_session(new session(io_service_));
    acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
        boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
          boost::asio::placeholders::error));
  }

  void handle_accept(session_ptr new_session,
      const boost::system::error_code& error)
  {
    if (!error)
    {
      new_session->start();
      new_session.reset(new session(io_service_));
      acceptor_.async_accept(new_session->socket(),
          boost::bind(&server::handle_accept, this, new_session,
            boost::asio::placeholders::error));
    }
  }

private:
  boost::asio::io_service& io_service_;
  tcp::acceptor acceptor_;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  try
  {
    if (argc != 2)
    {
      std::cerr << "Usage: reference_counted <port>\n";
      return 1;
    }

    boost::asio::io_service io_service;

    using namespace std; // For atoi.
    server s(io_service, atoi(argv[1]));

    io_service.run();
  }
  catch (std::exception& e)
  {
    std::cerr << "Exception: " << e.what() << "\n";
  }

  return 0;
}
```

As requested here is the giant block of error:

```
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `__static_initialization_and_destruction_0(int, int)':
example.cpp:(.text+0x182): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
example.cpp:(.text+0x18e): undefined reference to `boost::system::generic_category()'
example.cpp:(.text+0x19a): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::system::error_code::error_code()':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost6system10error_codeC2Ev[_ZN5boost6system10error_codeC5Ev]+0x17): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::error::get_system_category()':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio5error19get_system_categoryEv[boost::asio::error::get_system_category()]+0x5): undefined reference to `boost::system::system_category()'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail20posix_tss_ptr_createERj[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr_create(unsigned int&)]+0x19): undefined reference to `pthread_key_create'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::operator boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context*() const':
example.cpp:(.text._ZNK5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEEcvPS6_Ev[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::operator boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context*() const]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_getspecific'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::strand_service::strand_impl>::context>::~posix_tss_ptr()':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEE7contextEED2Ev[_ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_14strand_service11strand_implEE7contextEED5Ev]+0x15): undefined reference to `pthread_key_delete'
/tmp/ccvtengY.o: In function `boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::operator=(boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context*)':
example.cpp:(.text._ZN5boost4asio6detail13posix_tss_ptrINS1_10call_stackINS1_15task_io_serviceEE7contextEEaSEPS6_[boost::asio::detail::posix_tss_ptr<boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context>::operator=(boost::asio::detail::call_stack<boost::asio::detail::task_io_service>::context*)]+0x20): undefined reference to `pthread_setspecific'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It compiles fine for me with `g++ -lboost_system-mt -pthread`.

Comment: I know I needed Boost and I knew I was compiling multi-threaded. The documentation for Boost says to use `-lboost_system-mt` for multi-threaded code, and the documentation for my distribution says to use `-pthread` for POSIX pthread support. But if you didn't know that, you could use `nm` or `strings` to find the library that has the symbols you need.

Comment: Then log onto your machine and type `man nm` or `man strings`.

Comment: Oh I see, they're programs. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

For a list of linkable boost libraries:

```
for f in $(ls -1 /usr/lib64/libboost_*.a); do basename $f .a | cut -c 4-99; done;
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you may need to explicitly include the boost library path when you build.  What is your exact build command?  Do you have something like `-L/usr/lib/boost` in the command?